# C# Azure File Share is throwing error "Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

I am using the below code to copy the file to Azure File share. It is throwing error and Some times its working when I do

1. like reset the key by replacing the new key in connectionstring
2. by changing the time from cst and est in local machine( not all time working)

I am getting Error as

*Azure.RequestFailedException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b6a51c3f-b01a-0037-7774-d19906000000
Time:2022-09-26T06:53:52.3042347Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)*
*ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed
Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'Xrp6MB0=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
Thu, 22 Sep 2022 10:07:55 GMT
"0x8DA9C8251A37348"
x-ms-client-request-id:25ff53d8-7a55-414a-954b-ff8f6d05bced
x-ms-date:Mon, 26 Sep 2022 06:53:52 GMT
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
x-ms-version:2021-08-06*

*Content:
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b6a51c3f-
Time:2022-09-26T06:53:52.3042347ZThe MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'Xrp6MB0=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET*

I am using Access key 1 to access the Azure File share

Could someone let me know what is the error I am doing in the code

```c#
using Azure;
    using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=lPI20ZMzVjB9xcPmIJQjjIhFIuWs6JxTcxef7Ri3hRMtE3N1ov81gpabOVe+0BKEFiEZdhcAPhYC+ASt4Yjddw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    var fileShareName = "FileshareName";
    var folderName = "FolderName";
    ShareClient share = new(connectionString, fileShareName);
    if (!share.Exists())
    {
        share.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
    var directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(folderName);
    if(!directory.Exists())
    {
    directory.CreateIfNotExists();    
    }
    var directories = directory.GetFilesAndDirectories();
    
    string sFilename = "sample.pdf";
    string sPath = @"\\abc\Test.pdf";
    
    foreach (var s in directories)
    {
        if (s.Name == "Files")
        {
            var x = directory.GetSubdirectoryClient(s.Name);
            ShareFileClient file = x.GetFileClient(sFilename);
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(sPath))
            {
                file.Create(stream.Length);
                file.UploadRange(
                    new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),
                    stream);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Which line of code is giving you this error? Also, can you edit your question and include the complete error message?

Comment: @GauravMantri, I have posted the error in italics, The code is not failing at one line, some times it is failing at accessing the share/ Directory / sub directory / file. it is working if I do test after 30 minutes or if I change the access key in the connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (!share.Exists()) is not working and we need to write as **share.CreateIfNotExists().** It solved the Authentication error.

I believe the error is coming because of the date/time settings on the computer where your code is running.

If you notice the error message, the date/time returned by Azure Storage Service is `2022-09-26T06:53:52.3042347Z` however the date/time value sent in the request is `Thu, 22 Sep 2022 10:07:55 GMT`.

Because the current date/time on the machine where your code is running is about 4 days before the date/time on Azure Storage Service, the requests to Azure Storage are being rejected.

I would recommend taking a look at the date/time value on the local machine and make sure that it is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav Mantri, for finding the error, my machine date time is 9/26/2022.  Is there any way to force the request date

Comment: it is working once in 5 to 6 times. is there any ShareClient session to close

Comment: `is there any ShareClient session to close` - no. Is there something else that's running on your machine that might change the date/time?

Comment: Finally I found the Answer for this error, if (!share.Exists()) is wrong and we need to write as share.CreateIfNotExists(). It solved the Authentication error. Thank you @Gaurav.